# Apache accepts all websites that point to server

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I only have two websites pointed to my server IP, `Asite.com` and `Bsite.com`. I tried adding a website, so I pointed `Csite.com` to my server IP (but I haven't registered a virtualhost for site3.com yet). How come when I access `Csite.com` apache recognizes it as `Asite.com` even if I haven't registered a virtualhost for `Csite.com`?

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

**Asite.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName asite.com
        ServerAlias asite.com *.asite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/asite.com/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/asite.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

^The same goes for **Bsite.com**

Comment: Your use of `*` is the key. Use a specific domain in the `NameVirtualHost` and `VIrtualHost` directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first virtualhost is also the default:

"The asterisks match all addresses, so the main server serves no requests. Due to the fact that www.example1.com is first in the configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server. That means that if a request is received that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by this first VirtualHost."

See 'Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address.' http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

It uses the first-listed one, when it has no ServerName match.
You'll find you can also use the raw IP address to access Asite.com.

If you feel uncomfortable with that, you could create a different virtual host as the first one listed for `<VirtualHost *:8080>`, and configure so it just Redirects somewhere else. Or gives a 404 message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you pointed the  csite.com to your local host and the first virtual host is recognized as local host so if you switch around siteA and siteB so it would be virtual host for sure b first and type in your browser "localhost" or sitec.com it will show siteb.com

Don't worry; this isn't a problem. It is supposed to happen.

You didn't actually point sitec.com to localhost but I if you created it in your hosts file our pointed it to your domain it will take you to the first specified file!